# How to make first dropdown not render in reactjs and ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, antd

I need to make my current draggable component's dropdown to not render on specific cell (specifically the first Row). However, it will still show the cell just without the dropdown. I tried to search for a way however could not find any. Appreciate any help / directions given. Thanks! I also also attached the screenshot of current and expected. (Just take note of the dropdown being empty)

**Current Interface - all dropdown rendered*
[image: Current Interface - all dropdown rendered]

**Expected New Interface - first dropdown not rendered*
[image: Expected New Interface - first dropdown not rendered]

**Main code with ant design component Row/Col and Select/Option for the dropdown:**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table
          scroll={{ x: 300 }}
          pagination={{
            defaultPageSize: 10,
            showSizeChanger: true,
            pageSizeOptions: ['10', '25', '50'],
          }}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          dataSource={this.state.datas}
        ></Table>

        <Modal
          destroyOnClose={true}
          width={'80%'}
          title='Approval Sequence'
          visible={this.state.isVisible}
          onOk={() => {

            updateFlowType(this.state.currentItem.id, {
              name: this.state.currentItem.name,
              sites: this.state.initTags.map((x) => ({
                idSite: x.id,
                returnToStep: x.returnToStep,
              })),
            })
              .then((r) => {
                notification['sucess']({
                  message: 'Success',
                  description: 'Save data success',
                });
                this.setState({ isVisible: false });
                this.getData();
              })
              .catch(() => {
                notification['failed']({
                  message: 'Failed',
                  description: 'Failed to save',
                });
              });
          }}
          onCancel={() => {
            this.setState({ isVisible: false });
          }}
        >

          <Row gutter={[2, 2]}>
            <Col style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} span={8}>
              <Text strong>Role</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} span={8}>
              <Text strong> Return to Department: </Text>
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <div className='list-area'>
            <div className='drag-list'>
              <DraggableArea
                onChange={(initTags) => this.setState({ initTags })}
                isList
                tags={this.state.initTags}
                render={({ tag }) => (
                  <Row>
                    <Col span={8}>
                      <Button style={{ width: '100%' }}>{tag.name}</Button>
                    </Col>

                    <Col span={16}>
                      <Select
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          //create clone
                          let clone = [...this.state.initTags];
                          
                          let item = clone.find((x) => x.id === tag.id);
                          
                          let itemReject = clone.find((x) => x.name === e);

                          console.log('itemReject', itemReject);
                          //create returnToStep in item 
                          item.returnToStep = itemReject.id;
                          this.setState({
                            initTags: clone,
                          });
                        }}
                        //placeholder = 'Select return step'
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                      >
                        {this.getReject(tag.name).map((newTag) => (
                        //getReject function will slice to get only items before the current iteration object (e.g. if current is index 3, only get index 0~2)
                          <Option key={newTag.name} value={newTag.name}>
                            {newTag.name}
                          </Option>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                )}
              ></DraggableArea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do "conditional render" using a condition and a component like this:

```
const someBoolean = true;
retrun ( 
    { someBoolean && <SomeComponent /> }
)
```

if `someBoolean` is true, then `<SomeComponent/>`  will show.
if `someBoolean` is false, then `<SomeComponent/>` will not show.

So, just use that to conditionally render your dropdown column or any other component.

If, the table rows are based upon content and dynamically rendered, then I would modify the content accordingly. (i.e. don't provide the rows you don't want to render).

Comment: hi, i have tried to do a map before the <Select> tag.                       {(tag).map(tagObj, index) => {
                        if (index !== 0) { return <Select.... </Select>} however, it does not work. I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: tag.map is not a function" Can you suggest how i can do the conditional render you describe.

Comment: tag is not an array.  so it doesn't have a 'map' function.

Comment: you have an array called `tags`.  you can refer to the first index of it.  another option i see is you have the name for each tag  (tag.name)  so if you know the name of the "select" you want to hide it can be useful instead of depending on specifically the first.

Comment: So, before each `<select >`  you can try :   `{ tag.name !== 'ABC' && <select ...> }`  this way all will show except the tag named "ABC"...

Comment: Hi, what does the && means here? i thought it is a condition to check both to be true before proceeding the nested lines?

Comment: anyway that worked! thanks a lot :) Just not sure why does the && works here.. its kind of weird to put it logically

Comment: Yes, the && is a special "shortcut" syntax especially for these cases. If you need a more logically "readable" way, you can always write a function and do an "if else" to return either the component or empty string. like this pattern: `const myComp = () => { if (someCondition) return <MyComponent/> else return ''}` .   and then in the return statement you provide the {myComp} and whatever is there, it will be rendered...